# Scaling a triangle up or down given it's vertices and center point

Tags: algorithm, geometry

I am writing a program using OpenGL and I am trying to write a function that allows the user to click on a triangle and increase/decrease the size of the triangle by hitting keys on the keyboard. I understand how to handle key presses, but I am having a little trouble with the math.

If I have a triangle's three vertices and center point stored, how can I upscale the triangle? In other words, how can I manipulate the current vertices to make the triangle larger without altering the center point?

This was my first attempt at up-scaling, where v1, v2, and v3 are the vertices of the triangle and A, B, and C are the vertices of the triangle after being scaled up:

```
//distance from center to v1
double distance = center - v1;
distance = distance * 1.25;
Vector3d A = center + distance;

v1(0) = A(0);
v1(1) = A(1);


// v2
distance = center - center;
distance = distance * 1.25;
Vector3d B = center + distance;

v2(0) = B(0);
v2(1) = B(1);


// v3
distance = center - v3;
distance = distance * 1.25;
Vector3d C = center + distance;

v3(0) = C(0);
v3(1) = C(1);
```

edit:
  I am using the Eigen library, so v1(0) means the x-coordinate of vertex v1 and v1(1) means the y-coordinate of vertex v1

Comment: `distance = center - center;` is not the correct formula for v2

Comment: wow I cant believe i missed that....

Comment: I just fixed it though, and the triangle kind of rotates not increases in size

Comment: No one has formally answered yet so update the question with the revised code. Otherwise you'll just get more comments and answers targeting the trivial, and fixed, mistake.

Comment: Next trivial mistake:  Work thru your math using a scaling factor of `1.0` instead of `1.25`.  You should get the same values out that go in...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line

```
double distance = center - v1;
```

is certainly wrong. Both `center` and `v1` are points. That means that they have two or three components (depending on whether you work in 2D or 3D) and therefore `distance` cannot be a `double` (i.e., a scalar) but has to be a vector.

This is how I would compute `A` (computation of `B` and `C` will be analogous):

```
vector3d A;
for(std::size_t i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
  A(i) = center(i) + 1.25 * (V1(i) - center(i));
```

The part `V1(i) - center(i)` represents the *i*-th coordinate of the vector *(V1 - center)*. The right hand-side also represents "walking in the same direction from `center` but 1.25-times as far."

## A few further notes

- From your sample it is not clear, whether you work in 2D or 3D. On the one hand, you use `vector3d`, on the other hand you seem to manipulate with the *x*- and *y*-coordinates only.
- I don't understand, why you used `v1(0) = A(0);` From how I understand your question, `A` is already the answer.
- Instead of copy-pasting the essentially identical code three times (once for `A`, once for `B` and once for `C`) it might be useful to turn it into a function that you can call three times.

Good luck with your task!

Comment: Note:  `A(i) = center + 1.25 * (V1(i) - center));` is like `A(i) = (1.0 - 1.25)*center(i) + 1.25 * V1(i);` for an alternate form.